# How to save SqlCmd commands into a file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd, sql-scripts

I am using SqlCmd for SQL Server 2008. I want to save all the commands that I have typed in SqlCmd into a text file or script file. Is it possible? If so how to do so?

Comment: It's not too clear what you mean. You want an automated log of what you've typed into a sqlcmd session (not necessarily the results)?

Comment: @JustinStolle sorry for getting back late. Yes an automated log like what we use in Oracle, `pool` command. And also how to use a pre-written script to create/insert tables?

Comment: Do you mean the [`spool`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) command? The question about "a pre-written script" should be written up as a new question if you can't find one that already answers that for you.

Comment: Yup Spool... sorry s missing.